# Can`t register interface with regasm

Tags: c#, com, regasm

Trying to register interface, using regasm

I tried to play with AssemblyInfo.cs switching ComVisible, no luck.
I tried signing it.
Regasm always responds

RegAsm : warning RA0000 : No types were registered

My project is class library , .net 4.5.

My one cs file - Interface.cs looks like this:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace ComTestInterface
{


    [ComImport]
    [System.Security.SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity]
    [Guid("647ED2ED-78DB-4168-B50E-DD4C506EAF53")]
    [InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
    public interface ImageSourceFilter
    {
        void SetColor();
    }


}
```

Comment: This doesn't sound good, high odds that you are trying to shoot your left foot.  Do explain why you think you need to register it.

Comment: @HansPassant i need too access my directshow filter method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved.
I registered interface in same project where class located. With next code
Interface:

```
    [ComVisible(true)]
    [System.Security.SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity]
    [Guid("170BB172-4FD1-4eb5-B6F6-A834B344260F")]
    [InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
    public interface IImageSourceFilter
    {
        void SetColor();
    }
```

Class:

```
 [ComVisible(true)]
    [Guid("170BB172-4FD1-4eb5-B6F6-A834B344268F")]
    [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
    public class ImageSourceFilter : BaseSourceFilter,IImageSourceFilter
    {
  public void SetColor()
        {...}
     }
```

Also worth mentioning, that class need to inherit this interface.
Registration was completed with Post-Build event in project settings with parametrs:

```
"$(TargetDir)install.bat" $(TargetName)
```

And install.bat contained next:

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\RegAsm.exe %1.dll /nologo /codebase /tlb: %1.tlb
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `ComImport` attribute and add `ComVisible` attribute:

```
[ComVisible(true)]
[System.Security.SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity]
[Guid("647ED2ED-78DB-4168-B50E-DD4C506EAF53")]
[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
public interface ImageSourceFilter
{
    void SetColor();
}
```

Comment: Haven`t helped.

Comment: It should work. Post your full project somewhere, including the full regasm command line you run.